# Shimano inner cage plate replacement

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear, replacement

I have a broken inner cage plate on my Shimano Ultegra RD-6700 GS rear derailleur. This replacement part # is Y5VG09300, and I can't find this part anywhere.

I'd really hate to throw out a perfectly good Ultegra level RD for want of 1 broken part.

Can somebody recommend a compatible replacement inner cage plate, or somewhere I can buy the correct one?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In such cases, I often check ebay or similar marketplaces for a used/best offer/parts only item to scavenge the needed part from. One often needs to be patient and make multiple offers before succeeding. As far as compatible replacement parts, si.shimano.com documents may indicate compatible parts if you haven't checked there yet; alternatively, a local bike shop employee might know what works and where to get one.

Comment: spot on, take two broken ones and make a good one

Comment: There are also after-market parts available like carbon cages although some may be more expensive than a whole new derailleur.

Comment: The other option is to buy a new RD and use the previous one minus the broken part for spares.